# How does size work with memcpy?

Tags: c++, arrays, memcpy

My question relates to how safe the following code is:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

std::array<BYTE, ARRAY_SIZE> myArray;
char* string = "this_sentence_is_longer_than_10_bytes"

memcpy(&myArray, string, ARRAY_SIZE);
```

Result: myArray is filled `[0-9]` with `"this_sente"`

In terms of it being safe, I need to know what is happening to the rest of 'string'. Is it being ignored completely due to the size given or is it being thrown off the end of the array?

edit:
I now have

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

std::array<BYTE, ARRAY_SIZE> myArray;
char* string = "this_sentence_is_longer_than_10_bytes"

if (strlen(string) < ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    BYTE clearArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};
    memcpy(&myArray, clearArray, ARRAY_SIZE);
    memcpy(&myArray, string, strlen(string));
}
else
{
    memcpy(&myArray, string, ARRAY_SIZE);
}
```

It now pads out the std:array with zeroes if the string is shorter than 10 characters, otherwise it uses the initial method.

Comment: Why `memcpy` at all? In C++, use `std::copy` (or `std::copy_n`) instead.

Comment: BTW, it should be `const char* string`.

Comment: ...and if your compiler didn't tell you so, it is misconfigured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rest of the string constant gets ignored, as if it's not there. `memcpy` stops as soon as it reaches `size` bytes.

Note that although it is safe to pass a memory block that is larger than `size` to `memcpy`, passing a block that is shorter triggers undefined behavior. For example, if you pass `string` that has fewer than nine characters, `memcpy` will copy invalid characters past the end of the string into `myArray`.

Comment: @quantdev You are right, I took the `BYTE` name at its face value.

Comment: Thank you, any suggestions in terms of "pre-padding" the char* array if it is too short? And yes, BYTE is just unsigned char :)

Comment: @user1539405 You cannot pad an array - the only choice here is to pass a smaller value for the `size` (obviously, you do not need to fill the entire array if you do not have enough data for it).

Comment: Added an edit to my first post. Does that look about right? I filled the initial array with zeroes instead and then passed the smaller size so I am not left with older data.

Comment: @user1539405 Yes, your updated code is safe. You can make it more efficient by saving the results of `strlen`, and by using [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) instead of creating and copying a new array.

Comment: Thank you, will do :) Marking this answered.